# what is data-info in html?

Tags: html, arrays, html5-history

```
<!DOCTYE html>
<html lang="ae-ar">
<head data-info="f:msnallexpuser,muiflt13cf">
```

***I am not understand the function of data info above***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-*` attribute in HTML stores custom values. This stored data can be retrieved in JavaScript. In your case, `data-info` is the attribute name and its value is `f:msnallexpuser,muiflt13cf`. Value can be retrieved using `getAttribute` function in JavaScript.

Comment: It can also be used as a CSS selector `[data-*=""]` or just `[data-info]`

Answer (score 0):

> "HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

You could use `el.getAttribute('data-whatever')` to get the data attribute in JavaScript however a better way to get the HTML data attribute is to use `el.dataset.whatever`, whatever being what-ever you want.

You can also get data attributes in CSS as well using the `content: attr(data-whatever)` or the selector: `[data-whatever='value']` or `[data-whatever]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code which I copied from [W3Schools HTML data-* Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) tutorial will help you to understand it easily.

```js
function showDetails(animal) {
  var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
  alert("The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".");
}
```

```html
<h1>Species</h1>
<p>Click on a species to see what type it is:</p>

<ul>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>  
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>  
</ul>
```

If you want the definition and usage, for it, I also have copied and pasted it for you.

> The data-* attribute is used to store custom data private to the page
> or application.
>
> The data-* attribute gives us the ability to embed custom data
> attributes on all HTML elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to
> create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or
> server-side database queries).
>
> The data-* attribute consist of two parts:
>
> The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must
> be at least one character long after the prefix "data-" The attribute
> value can be any string Note: Custom attributes prefixed with "data-"
> will be completely ignored by the user agent.
>
> The data-* attribute is a Global Attribute, and can be used on any
> HTML element.

Thanks and best regards!